# is there a way to export bash shell options to subshell?

Tags: bash, shell

I set bash options (e.g. shopt -e autocd) in current shell & want to export/copy this options to a newly created subshell. Is there a way to do this?

Bash Version is: GNU bash, Version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Example:

```
$shopt -s autocd
$shopt autocd
autocd          on
$bash
$shopt autocd
autocd          off
```

Comment: Should be moved to unix.stackexchange.

Comment: Why? Can you please explain? I checked tags for bash before posting this question: much more questions related to bash in stackoverflow compared to unix, ...
And decided to post in stackoverflow based on this statistics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export many shell options analogous to shell variables by using the corresponding shell variable BASHOPTS which stores the shell options:

```
export BASHOPTS
```

Here is some information of the Bash man page:

> BASHOPTS:
>   A colon-separated list of enabled shell options.  Each word in the list is a valid argument for the -s option to the shopt builtin command (see SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).  The options appearing in BASHOPTS are those reported as on by shopt.  If this variable is in the environment when bash starts up, each shell option in the list will be enabled before reading any startup files.  This variable is read-only.

There is a closely related variable SHELLOPTS, but this only seems to work well if bash is invoked directly (e.g. via **bash**) rather than via **sh** because **sh** enables the POSIX mode of Bash. [Here](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2011-10/msg00052.html) is more information on this issue.

Comment: You mean `export BASHOPTS`? OP uses `shopt`.

Comment: @flow2k: Yes it seems you are right, thanks for the hint. :-) I have updated my answer.

Comment: BASHOPTS works fine. Don't understand, why SHELLOPTS is related? As far as I understand it, BASHOPTS is for *shopt* and SHELLOPTS is for *set*

Comment: @MichaelBrux: You are right if you mean that SHELLOPTS ans BASHOPTS are different from each other. But they can be seen as related to each other since they both store shell options, just different ones. And they can be "copied into the subshell" (to use the words of the OP) via the same export mechanism. Moreover, many people don't know that there even exist two types of shell options, therefore it seemded good to mention the related SHELLOPTS.